How to override same method one time in derived class
// From standard java library.
class ThreadPoolExecutor {}
class ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {} // derived class

interface Enhance {
  default Runnable enhanceTask(Runnable command) {
    // wrap runnable
    ...
  }
}
class CommonThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor implements Enhance {}
class CommonScheduledThreadPoolExecutor extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor implements Enhance {}

If I want to enhance the execute method in ThreadPoolExecutor, I must write same @Override twice:
class CommonThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor implements Enhance {
  @Override
  public void execute(@NonNull Runnable command) {
    Runnable runnable = enhanceTask(command);
    super.execute(runnable);
  }
}

class CommonScheduledThreadPoolExecutor extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor implements Enhance {
  @Override
  public void execute(@NonNull Runnable command) {
    Runnable runnable = enhanceTask(command);
    super.execute(runnable);
  }
}

Must keep instances are assignable to ThreadPoolExecutor or ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

Maybe you can create a abstract class of sorts for the Executor --> EnhancedExecutor then have your other classes inherit from this.

@BIBOOunit This wouldn't work as both classes need to extend from different classes. Another option would be using composition over inheritence but I don't think that would make that much of a difference for this problem.

ThreadPoolExecutor and ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor are those the classes from the standart java library, or something you declared?

@Override protected void beforeExecute ?

@tresf That method won't let OP wrap the task in another Runnable and then execute the wrapper. They'd also still have to override that method in both subclasses, which is what they're trying to avoid.

@Chaosfire Standard java library.

isn't  ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor extending ThreadPoolExecutor? If CommonScheduledThreadPoolExecutor extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, it will be both "assignable to ThreadPoolExecutor or ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor" (no need for CommonThreadPoolExecutor)

@BIBOOunit I missed to mention that ThreadPoolExecutor and ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor are from standard java library. So they cannot be modified.

user85421's idea could work for you (subclass ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and then use instances of that class everywhere, even in places where you only need a ThreadPoolExecutor). You can still configure the keep-alive time and max pool size via setters. You just won't have control over the queue type anymore.

What's the issue here? Do you have to extend multiple subclasses of ThreadPoolExecutor? Or do you see yourself needing to refactor the overridden execute method in the future and hence you want this code in one place?

@user85421 Yes, I missed your point. I think your advice is practicable.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you are trying to write a single method with logic for "execute" method for both CommonThreadPoolExecutor and CommonScheduledThreadPoolExecutor you can try something like this:
Step 1: Create a Utility Class with a Static Method
This method will handle the enhancement of the task and execution logic, reducing the duplication in each class.
public class ExecutorUtils {
    public static void executeEnhanced(Runnable command, ThreadPoolExecutor executor, Enhance enhancer) {
        Runnable enhancedRunnable = enhancer.enhanceTask(command);
        executor.execute(enhancedRunnable);
    }
}

Step 2: Modify Your Executor Classes
You can then simplify your executor classes to call this utility method keeping logic for the execute method in one place.
class CommonThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor implements Enhance {
  @Override
  public void execute(@NonNull Runnable command) {
    ExecutorUtils.executeEnhanced(command, this, this);
  }
}

class CommonScheduledThreadPoolExecutor extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor implements Enhance {
  @Override
  public void execute(@NonNull Runnable command) {
    ExecutorUtils.executeEnhanced(command, this, this);
  }
}

